# A simple question about 1D finite element derivatives

Tags: finite-element

For 1D derivative we have
   \begin{equation}
    F(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
    f(x)=\sum_{i}f_ie_i(x)
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
    F(x)=\sum_{i}F_ie_i(x)
   \end{equation}
where $e_i(x)$ are the FEM basis functions. We can then apply the Galerkin procedure to the derivative,and then get the matrix form
\begin{equation}
A\widehat{F}=B\widehat{f}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\widehat{F}=A^{-1}B\widehat{f}
\end{equation}
$\widehat{F}$and$\widehat{f}$are the vector form of $F_i$and $f_i$.

For the derivative of the product of two functions $f(x)$and $g(x)$,applying product rule we get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial (f(x).g(x))}{\partial x}=f(x). \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}+g(x). \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

Now in FEM I want the derivative matrix $C=A^{-1}B$ also to fulfill the similar constraint
\begin{equation}
C \widehat{fg} = [f]_{dig}.C\widehat{g} + [g]_{dig}.C\widehat{f} 
\end{equation}
where $[f]_{dig}$ means diagonal matrix with the values $f_i$ in it.

Does any body know what kinds of basis function $e_i(x)$  I can chose?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest basis functions are piecewise linear functions with value $1$ one mesh point and value $0$ at all the others, shown in this image from [here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_finite_elements/Finite_element_basis_functions):

[image]

Higher order polynomials can be used through [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) (rather than linear) in each "mesh" interval of the 1D domain. There are some good images of quadratic and cubic basis functions on [this page](http://hplgit.github.io/INF5620/doc/pub/sphinx-fem/._main_fem003.html).